# show that $e^{f(z)}=z$ for a specific complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given are $\log s$ (for $s>0$) and $\arctan t$ (for $t\in\mathbb{R}$) the usual real functions.

Define on $U=\{z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}|x\neq 0\}$ the following function: 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^2+y^2)+i\arctan \frac{y}{x}.$$

I already showed that $f$ is holomorphic on $U$. I also showed that $f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ for $z\in U$.

The last thing I have to show is that $e^{f(z)}=z$ on $\{z\in U|x>0\}$ and $e^{f(z)}=-z$ on $\{z\in U|x<0\}$.

I think it might help to use the differentiating property of the exponential, but I think I might be using it in a wrong way because until so far it doesn't help me..

Who can help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: The $\log$ is a multi-valued function, so when you use it, you have to say which specific branch you are using.  Each branch is defined in the complex plane minus a ray that emanates from the origin.

Comment: By the identity principle, it is enough to prove the result for real $z$: in such a case, the result is obvious.

Comment: @avs He is clearly using the usual $\log$ since $x^2+y^2$ is a positive real number.

Comment: @Crostul, for me it is not obvious.. could you help me with it?

Comment: When $z$ is real, then $x=z$ and $y=0$. Now, $$e^{f(z)} = e^{\frac{1}{2} \log x^2} = |x|$$ which is equal to $z$ when $x >0$ and $-z$ when $x<0$. By the identity principle, those two holomorphic functions coincide on the whole domain $U$. Obviously all of this is not meaningful if you don't know the identity principle.

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, then so is $g(z) = e^{f(z)}-z$.  A holomorphic function on a connected open set that is not constant there has only isolated zeros...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the auxiliary function $g(z):=z\>e^{-f(z)}$. Using the chain rule prove that $g'(z)\equiv0$. It follows that $g$ is constant on any connected open set where $f$ is defined. Now determine the constants valid when $x>0$, resp.,  $x<0$ by plugging in $z=\pm1$.